# Can't change the width of Kendo upload component using css (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Working with a typical ASP.NET MVC site.

Adding the following to site.css and it doesn't work.

```
.k-upload {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Here's what's being generated by my bundles:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

I want the upload div to be the width of the input boxes (280px).

Here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image: Here's a screenshot of the problem.]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the old css was cached in Chrome. Flushed the cache and the css listed above works perfectly.